# converting numpy array weird issue

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, svm

I have following data

```
3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 12 41 146 146 48 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 12 129 253 253 253 250 163 18 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 133 253 253 253 253 253 253 229 70 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 101 253 252 145 102 107 237 253 247 128 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 181 253 167 0 0 0 61 235 253 253 163 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 255 253 43 0 0 0 0 58 193 253 253 164 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 187 253 32 0 0 0 0 0 55 236 253 253 86 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 146 253 32 0 100 190 87 87 87 147 253 253 123 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 94 253 78 40 248 253 253 253 253 253 253 253 223 84 15 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14 92 12 35 240 253 253 253 253 253 253 253 253 253 244 89 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 75 161 179 253 253 253 253 253 253 253 253 253 209 43 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 16 16 39 38 16 16 145 243 253 253 185 48 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 20 58 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 58 209 253 253 183 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 77 221 247 79 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 13 219 253 240 72 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 90 247 253 252 57 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 53 251 253 191 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 116 253 253 59 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 99 252 253 145 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 14 188 253 221 158 38 0 0 0 0 111 211 246 253 253 145 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 12 221 246 253 251 249 249 249 249 253 253 253 253 200 19 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 95 183 228 253 253 253 253 253 253 195 124 23 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 24 37 138 74 126 88 37 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Column 1 is the label of an image and others are the pixels. That is there are 785 columns where the first column is label other 784 are 28*28 pixel images. I am trying to get data is the following format

`for column 1:array([ 3.,....])) and for column 2-784: (array([[  0.....0]])`, that is type `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>, <type 'numpy.ndarray'>`

I am using the following method to read the data

```
data='~/train.csv'
dataset = genfromtxt(dataset, delimiter=",", dtype=np.dtype('>i4'))[1:]

def gen_lin_separable_overlap_data():
        labels = [x[0] for x in dataset]
        data = [x[1:]/float(x.max()) for x in dataset] # with scaling

        return labels, data
```

I tried to use following steps to convert the data into desired shape:

```
labels, data =gen_lin_separable_overlap_data() #reads the data
labels=np.array(labels)
data=np.array(data) #or np.array([data])
```

Output:

```
`labels.shape #(40,) 
for np.array([data]), data.shape #(1, 40, 784)
for data=np.array(data), data.shape(40,784)`
```

It yields output as:

that is `[3 ..., 3 3 ] [[0......0]]`

All I am missing is the formatting as above. Any help on this regards is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy has the function [`loadtxt()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) for reading text files into an array, I think this is far easier to use for your purposes.

```
import numpy as np
imgs = np.loadtxt('train.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=np.uint8)[:, 1:].reshape(-1, 28, 28)
print(imgs.shape)
```

> (3, 28, 28)

Here the file `train.csv` contained three lines in my case, so there's three images. Note the reshape function creates a new axis for each image (so that `imgs[0]` is the first image and so on, and `len(imgs)` is the number of images) and each image is given the size (28, 28).